# How to open and close gui?

Tags: roblox

## I have a problem with the Script to open and close the gui.

My plan was to open the gui using the part in the Workshop. As soon as I click on the part it will show the gui and there will be another button (textButton) in the gui in StarterGui and it will close the gui. I have a script for the part but it doesn't work and I don't have any script for the TextButton. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Script for the part:

```
local starterGui = game:GetService("StarterGui")
local clickDetector = script.Parent -- Assuming this code is inside a LocalScript attached to the ClickDetector

local function onClick()
    local screenGui = starterGui:WaitForChild("Hlavní") -- Replace "ScreenGui" with the actual name of your ScreenGui

    screenGui.Enabled = true
end

clickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(onClick)
```

I've tried just about everything

Answer (score 0):

Is this a script or a localscript? Guis can only be controlled in a local script.

if it is a script, add a remote event in the Replicated Storage, name it 'OpenShop' and type this in the script.

```
local starterGui = game:GetService("StarterGui")
local clickDetector = script.Parent -- Assuming this code is inside a LocalScript attached to the ClickDetector

clickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(plr)
    game.ReplicatedStorage.OpenShop:FireClient(plr)
end)
```

Then, add a localscript in the "Hlavní" GUI, type in all this.

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.OpenShop.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
     local screenGui = game.StarterGui:WaitForChild("Hlavní")
end)
```

I didn't test it, so tell me if you have any problem. I might have some spelling mistakes.